# Move letters from the volume to the journal field using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have automatically generated bibtex entries such as:

```
@article{Gasser:1984gg,
      author         = "Gasser, J. and Leutwyler, H.",
      title          = "{Chiral Perturbation Theory: Expansions in the Mass of
                        the Strange Quark}",
      journal        = "Nucl. Phys.",
      volume         = "B250",
      year           = "1985",
      pages          = "465-516",
      doi            = "10.1016/0550-3213(85)90492-4",
      reportNumber   = "CERN-TH-3798",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = NUPHA,B250,465;%%"
}

@article{Leutwyler:1992yt,
      author         = "Leutwyler, H. and Smilga, Andrei V.",
      title          = "{Spectrum of Dirac operator and role of winding number in
                        QCD}",
      journal        = "Phys. Rev.",
      volume         = "D46",
      year           = "1992",
      pages          = "5607-5632",
      doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.46.5607",
      reportNumber   = "BUTP-92-10",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = PHRVA,D46,5607;%%"
}

@article{Chou:1983qy,
      author         = "Chou, Kuang-chao and Guo, Han-ying and Wu, Ke and Song,
                        Xing-chang",
      title          = "{On the Gauge Invariance and Anomaly Free Condition of
                        {Wess-Zumino}-witten Effective Action}",
      journal        = "Phys. Lett.",
      volume         = "134B",
      year           = "1984",
      pages          = "67-69",
      doi            = "10.1016/0370-2693(84)90986-9",
      reportNumber   = "AS-ITP-83-027",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = PHLTA,134B,67;%%"
}
```

Unfortunately, the last letter of the journal field is sometimes stored as the first or last letter of the volume field.
Is there a way using `biblatex` to automatically move letters from the beginning or the end of the volume field to the end of the journal field?
Therefore, I would like to treat the entries on the left as if they have been given in the form on the right:

```
journal        = "Nucl. Phys.",      -->      journal        = "Nucl. Phys. B",
volume         = "B250",             -->      volume         = "250",
```

```
journal        = "Phys. Rev.",       -->      journal        = "Phys. Rev. D",
volume         = "D46",              -->      volume         = "46",
```

```
journal        = "Phys. Lett.",      -->      journal        = "Phys. Lett. B",
volume         = "134B",             -->      volume         = "134",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `biblatex` you can use Biber sourcemaps to manipulate the input data from the `.bib` file.

The additional mapping step `\step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]` is needed because the `journal` field is internally called `journaltitle` and the automatic mapping that would usually take care of this is executed at the wrong time.

It may be useful to correct your `.bib` file only once and then work with a cleaned version of your file instead of having Biber perform the mapping every time.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=volume, match=\regexp{\A(\p{L}+)?\d+(\p{L}+)?\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=volume, match=\regexp{\A(\p{L}+)?(\d+)(\p{L}+)?\Z}, replace={$2}]
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle, fieldvalue={\space$1$2}, append=true]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gasser,
  author         = {Gasser, J. and Leutwyler, H.},
  title          = {Chiral Perturbation Theory: Expansions in the Mass of
                    the Strange Quark},
  journal        = {Nucl. Phys.},
  volume         = {B250},
  year           = {1985},
  pages          = {465-516},
  doi            = {10.1016/0550-3213(85)90492-4},
  reportNumber   = {CERN-TH-3798},
}
@article{leutwyler,
  author         = {Leutwyler, H. and Smilga, Andrei V.},
  title          = {Spectrum of {Dirac} Operator and Role of Winding Number in
                    {QCD}},
  journal        = {Phys. Rev.},
  volume         = {D46},
  year           = {1992},
  pages          = {5607-5632},
  doi            = {10.1103/PhysRevD.46.5607},
  reportNumber   = {BUTP-92-10},
}
@article{chou,
  author         = {Chou, Kuang-chao and Guo, Han-ying and Wu, Ke and Song,
                    Xing-chang},
  title          = {On the Gauge Invariance and Anomaly Free Condition of
                    {Wess--Zumino--Witten} Effective Action},
  journal        = {Phys. Lett.},
  volume         = {134B},
  year           = {1984},
  pages          = {67-69},
  doi            = {10.1016/0370-2693(84)90986-9},
  reportNumber   = {AS-ITP-83-027},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{gasser,leutwyler,chou,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Chou, Kuang-chao et al. (1984). ‘On the Gauge Invariance and Anomaly Free Condition of Wess–Zumino–Witten Effective Action’. In: Phys. Lett. B 134, pp. 67–69. doi: 10.1016/0370-2693(84)90986-9.//Gasser, J. and H. Leutwyler (1985). ‘Chiral Perturbation Theory: Expansions in the Mass of the Strange Quark’. In: Nucl. Phys. B 250, pp. 465–516. doi:10.1016/0550-3213(85)90492-4.//Leutwyler, H. and Andrei V. Smilga (1992). ‘Spectrum of Dirac Operator and Role of Winding Number in QCD’. In: Phys. Rev. D 46, pp. 5607–5632. doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.46.5607.//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Great solution! I work with different people and everybody can bring in new references. It is better to waste a bit of compilation time than to publish a ill-formatted reference list.